# Automatic function call I can use besides componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want some items being rendered to the screen automatically when a user goes to the route. However, because these items are obtained from an api request that requires an authorization token, I have to wait for my this.props.user to be populated because it contains my token. My this.props.user property is populated via an api request to the backend of my website, which takes some time, long enough such that my this.props.user is STILL null even when componentDidMount() is called, which contains the code that makes the authorized api request. Consequently, because my componentDidMount() does not have a this.props.user property filled, it cannot send the authorized request, and I don't know how else to automatically render the obtained items, which I will put into my redux store.

I tried writing the code that gets the authorized request in a separate function, because by then, my this.props.user property is properly filled. However, if I make a call to that function in my render(), it gets called in a loop that never ends. I think the forever loop is because of the redux update.

Does anyone know what I can do to make an automatic authorized request only once? Maybe wait for componentDidMount() to be called only once this.props.user is not null?

EDIT: I just added a setTimeout in componentDidMount() that calls the authorized request, so that it's called a second later, which will allow the this.props.user to populate, and that seems to work. Only problem is that it feels quite hack-y. If anyone has any other suggestions, I would be open to them!

Comment: This does indeed seem hacky. It's hard to give any advice on how to improve it without knowing more about your code. It's best to avoid side effects in the render method. Instead you can use `componentWillReceiveProps()` or `constructor`. The methods you can use are described in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround will probably not work if the API request that populates props.user fails.
A possible solution may be to check props.user in componentDidMount and if it is null display a message that says that authentication is not completed, and ask the user to wait few seconds and refresh.
You should also have a way to know that the API request failed, in order to tell the user that an error happened and she/he should check the internet connection and refresh or another relevant message.